# Ethernet throughput bottlenecks

Tags: networking, performance, gigabit-ethernet, wired-networking

I'm trying to figure out the bottlenecks of a typical wired network. In my case, the network is closed off where I have many single board computers communicating to my laptop via a switch. I'm using a Dell XPS 15 Laptop

I was looking at the [Sonnet Solo 10G Thunderbolt](http://www.sonnettech.com/product/solo-10g-tb3.html). It seems like it allows for a throughput of 10G.

I'm thinking that there are a couple of bottlenecks I need to consider:

- Switch capabilities
- Ethernet capabilities (would I need Cat6a or Cat7?)
- Laptop network card needs to be able to handle 10G (Or does this Thunderbolt adapter use its own network interface?)

Are these the appropriate bottlenecks of the system? Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 1):

You are right. However, you're missing the most important part:

Your internet source must be 10G (your ISP must be able to send you 10Gp/s of internet, thus if you want those speeds, you need to pay for them).

Only **after** you've achieved that, you can start thinking about the rest of the bottlenecks (getting 10Gp/s from your ISP is a tough, tough job).

- Router capabilities: Many new and modern routers do support GigabitEthernet, however, for speeds only up to 1GBitp/s. You need a router whose ports do support 10Gp/s of throughput (not just the WAN port, but LAN as well).
- Switch capabilities: Next thing is that your switch needs to support 10G network throughput. You need a switch with 10G Nbase-T ports and a backplane supporting that speed, since you are connected to a switch.
- Then you need the proper cables for that. Cat6a (or even Cat6 would work depending on the distance) or Cat7 Ethernet cables must be used.
- The thunderbolt port just uses your network interface card you already have, it is one. The maximum throughput you can achieve depends on the type of the network card, but I really doubt it supports up to 10GBp/s. You need **802.3an** support for 10G through UTP, **802.3ae** for fiber, and **802.3ak** for coaxial cables.

After that, to enable it, you need to go to Thunderbolt settings and Update the Thunderbolt-Ethernet adapter.

If you believe your laptop does not support 10Gp/s, I've found an external NIC that you can use:
[Thunderbolt 3 to 2-port 10GbE NIC Chassis](https://www.startech.com/Networking-IO/Adapter-Cards/thunderbolt-3-10-gbe-nic-chassis~BNDTB310GNDP) (not an ad)

Only such a device can let you achieve such speeds, if your internal NIC does not support 10Gp/s.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I've added a bit more detail, like how my network is closed off. Also that I am using a Dell XPS 15 laptop not a macbook.

I don't understand the wording of your third point first sentence. You're saying that the  thunderbolt port is a network interface? Or is uses the network interface card?

Comment: @tyleax It uses the network interface card, it is not an interface itself.

Comment: I'm guessing the Thunderbolt adapter I linked is probably mainly used for desktop computers rather then laptops than? I don't think its standard for laptops to have 10G NIC's installed... Is there a work around this? Are there external NIC's you can buy for your laptop to handle 10G throughput

Comment: Unfortunately cannot find any specifications for your laptop's NIC. All I found is that it can support 1Gp/s, but haven't found confirmation for 10Gp/s. And no, you can only get external WiFi NICs, not Ethernet ones. Anyways, why would you want a 10G connection for a home network? That truly is overkill. Most applications do have limitations, as even they can't output that much. 1G should be more than enough if you're asking me.

Comment: @tyleax as you've mentioned that you also use a switch, I've edited my answer accordingly. Your switch needs to support 10G as well.

Comment: The application isn't for home network, its for a project where the laptop acts as a master and a bunch of single board computers acts as slaves passing large amount of content back to the master.